# Lie groups and orthogonal group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, analytic-functions

Are orthogonal groups are lie groups? I think parameter space points corresponds to  elements with determinant -1 break analytic property of  lie groups , what is the general condition to check a group is lie group or not ?

Comment: An analogy: would you consider the nonzero real numbers $\mathbf R^\times$ *not* to be a Lie group because the sign function is $-1$ on negative numbers? Lie groups do not have to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, orthogonal groups are Lie groups. Since, $O(n,\mathbb R)$ consists of two copoes of $SO(n,\mathbb R)$, if $SO(n,\mathbb R)$ is a Lie group, then so is $O(n,\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 0):

Orthogonal groups can be defined over arbitrary fields $K$ as the subgroup of the general linear group $GL_n(K)$ given by
$$
 \operatorname {O} (n,K)=\left\{Q\in \operatorname {GL} (n,K)\;\left|\;Q^{\mathsf {T}}Q=QQ^{\mathsf {T}}=I\right.\right\}. 
$$
Now for example, for a *finite* field we obtain a finite group, which is  also a compact discrete Lie group of dimension $0$.

Real orthogonal groups are real linear groups and hence real Lie groups.